# How to remove airline themes notice when running vim?

Tags: vim, spf13vim

I just installed spf13-vim and get this warning when running vim:

```
airline themes have been migrated to github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline-themes
and will be removed from the core in the near future.
```

How would I fix or disable the notice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply clone the vim-airline/vim-airline-themes repository as well. The warning from airline will then disappear.